# Wordpress URL Redirect (Error 404)

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have a dedicated server for my Wordpress: `www.example.com`

And I need to include a PHP process and host the new process at `www.example.com/myApp`

The problem I have is that although in the root of the server I create the folder `myApp`, when I try to access WordPress detected the URL and shows me "error 404" by default... Is there any way to tell WordPress to ignore the request when the URL is: `www.example.com/myApp`?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried changing the domain name www.example.com to www.example.com/myApp in your database table values?

Comment: My website must work in www.example.com, I think is best not to change this domain in Wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an exclusion in rewrite engine of the .htaccess of your website.

Try adding something like this:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
or 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !yourApp

Wordpress ignores urls with existing folders/files so basically you shouldn't having problems like this but you may try editing your .htaccess.